# How to write React. FC arrow function with generics?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, arrow-functions

Please help me.
I want to write React.FC with generics in the form of arrow function. But it doesn't work out.
After some time, I came to this decision

```
interface IProps<T> {
  onSelect: (value: string) => string | void;
  placeholder?: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  options?: T[];
  startTabIndex?: number;
}
```

As a result, I got the following

```
export const InputSelect = <T extends {}>(props: IProps<T>) => {...}
```

But I need to bind to React.FC. I can't figure out where to write it

Comment: what exactly does not work? What "does not work" mean in this context? Do you see some error, or what?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.